# What is a sensible way for a server to listen when client connections are going to be few and far between (with socket programming on linux)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking, client-server

I have to listen to a port for incoming client connections and serve them with some data. TO handle multiple client connections, I will need to `listen()` and `accept()` in a loop.

However, I know that there are going to be very few client connections. So it doesn't not make a lot of sense to continuously run `listen()` and `accept()` in a loop - just seems wasteful.

Am I crazy or is there a better way of doing this.

I was also thinking that if I `sleep()` my thread that runs the while loop for one second, I will still hog the CPU a lot less (50% less ? (since the loop is working only every alternate second ..)). But in this case if a client connection comes in whilst the thread was sleeping, will I miss the connection ? Or does the OS take care of that for me (i.e. it realises that there is a listen fired on that port and queues the request somehow for the listen to consume at a later point) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you listen when client connections are going to be abundant.

You only need to `listen()` once -- this binds the socket to accept connections.  `accept()` will *block* until a connection is received on this socket.  While it is blocked it will be waiting on the OS to indicate that a new connection has come in; during this time the thread will be sleeping.

So in this model, you should have one or more threads dedicated to serving requests from the existing connections, and one single thread that will simply `accept()` a new socket and add it to your list of open sockets.  While this thread is waiting for new connections it will not be using any CPU time, so there is no waste.

(You could also use the `epoll()` mechanism to perform all of these tasks on a single thread.  In either case, the act of waiting for a new connection to come in costs no CPU time.)

---

To answer your question regarding what happens if you are not blocked in `accept()` and a new connection comes in: yes, the operating system maintains a queue of incoming connections.  Each call to `accept()` will return the first such connection in the queue.  (If nothing is in the queue at that moment, then it will block until there is a new connection.)

Comment: so you are saying that `listen()` does not need to be in the while loop, just `accept()` ? And that I must store the sockets returned by `accept()` to serve my clients ?

Comment: Right, you only call `accept()` from the loop.  `listen()` is part of the initial listening socket setup and should only be called once.  Presumably you must store the accepted connection's socket *somewhere* if you are going to serve the client anything; how exactly you do that is outside the scope of your question.  Storing them in some kind of list/array is one way to do this, just be sure if you are using multiple threads that you synchronize access in some way.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out D.J. Bernstein's tcpserver (see http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html). Basically, you can simply run your c/c++ program under tcpserver, and tcpserver will handle everything as far as setting up the sockets, listing for incoming connections on whatever port you are using, etc. When an incoming connection arrives on the port that you specify, tcpserver will spawn an instance of your program and pipe incoming info from the client to your program's STDIN, and pipe outgoing info from your program's STDOUT back to the client.

Comment: Bernstein's tcpserver sounds a lot like inetd/xinetd.